# Slow query with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following sql query that take only 1 second to execute:

```
select a.date, b.rate, c.type, a.value from

a inner join b on a.id = b.aid
c inner join b.id = c.bid
where a.name = 'xxx'
```

But I need a resultset to get the results that has rate greater than 0. So when I change the query to this it takes 7 minutes to execute:

```
select a.date, b.rate, c.type, a.value from

a inner join b on a.id = b.aid
c inner join b.id = c.bid
where a.name = 'xxx' and b.rate>0
```

Why would this make the query time go up from 1 sec to 7 mins? Since the b table is huge I even tried to use CTE but that did not improve the performance either. I thought with the CTE there will be smaller set of values to filter from so it should be faster but that did not help:

```
;with x as
(select a.date, b.rate, c.type, a.value from

a inner join b on a.id = b.aid
c inner join b.id = c.bid
where a.name = 'xxx')
select * from x where rate>0
```

I cannot include the execution plan as I don't have permissions to db other than querying.

Comment: Is there an index on column `rate`?

Comment: SQL is not executed as naively as that.  You will almost certainly find that both with and without the CTE you get the exact same execution plan.  Try updating all statistics *(and recompiling the code if it's in a stored procedure)*, ensuring that you have all necessary indexes, and then trying again.

Comment: Is there an index on a.name? How many rows are there with the same name that you're after? How many of those have a rate > 0? How many rows in total? 7 minutes seems excessive to me, like something else we don't know about is going seriously wrong.

Comment: there is no index on column rate.

Comment: @Aaron, with the first query it takes a second to execute and outputs 173 rows out of which 167 rows have rate>0. But, individually table a, b, c have more than million records respectively.

Comment: Create indexes on rate & name columns & you will see a great difference.

Comment: @Yaqub when making vague suggestions like that please be more specific. Do you mean a single index with multiple columns, or two separate indexes?

Comment: since the columns belongs to two different tables, so two separate indexes will be required.

Comment: @user799891 - Have you tried updating the statistics?  And please could you confirm exactly which indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: @user799891, would it be possible for your DBA to grant you SHOWPLAN permissions if you are positive you don't have them already? Having the execution plan would help greatly in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I did updatestatistics but still the query the slow. There is only one primary key index on the b table and that is id.

Comment: I assume these are not real table names, column names or parameter values. Are you providing the variables (such as `0` for `rate`) via parameters?  If so it's possible that `OPTION RECOMPILE` will prevent the query from using a plan based on a bad parameter, at the cost of additional compilation resources every time. Sometimes that's a very good trade-off to make.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is that the slow execution plan is doing  the `rate>0` filter in an unfortunate way, like as part of a scan on the inside of a loop join or something.

If it comes down to it, one solution would be to store an intermediate result set and filter it in a separate statement.

I suggest this with the understanding that you can't make changes to your vendor's database and that you are basically stuck. This is essentially taking away some control from the optimizer -- something you don't typically want to do -- and is also adding a relatively small amount of overhead with the creation of a temp table. But it should alleviate the slowness in this case. I would continue to work with your vendor on indexing strategies if possible.

```
select a.date, b.rate, c.type, a.value 
into #t
from a inner join b on a.id = b.aid
c inner join b.id = c.bid
where a.name = 'xxx' 

select * from #t where rate>0
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your suggestion and the query is fast now. I used your method as a quick fix as by the time, I can get the access from DBA and get the vendor approval for adding additional indexes would take atleast few months. But we already started the process of working with the vendor. Thanks again

Comment: I'd recommend to `drop table` after use; otherwise, it only gets deallocated when the user ends their session, which might not be after the 2nd `select` here. Better yet: use a `@table_variable`, but unfortunately there's no convenient/lazy `into` syntax available for those.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me explain why you got a bad plan. One thing is what I could think as of now.
when there was no rate.The table a was first and based on sarg and index say it estimated 10000 rows.
This might have used a merge join.Now to join with table b (as of now assuming there is 1 to n mapping and on avg there are 2 rows for each row form a). Then the estimated rows after join is 20000 and then it is being joined with the table C.Now based on how big is the table C it could have used say Merge Join.Say actual rows were in 100's of thousands

But when you added the SARG rate > 0. Then the optimizer has not estimated 20K rows after join of A and B but instead estimated 6667 rows(30% as default for > 0 when there are no auto_create_statistics on) and then it might have chosen say nested loop join with the table C instead of merge join.But actual rows could have been much more and thus nested loop join could have been used for 100's of thousands and thus the final nested loop join might be taking this much of time.

In summary what i am trying to say is that because of extra sarg there was improper estimates from optimizer and thus a bad plan.

You do not create index here at all.Index is not the solution for each and every thing there are way too many overhead of having them and in specially your case the less restrictiev query is runing much better so issue is not to do with index but it is more to do with the statistics. Check following

> Is auto_create_statistics on or off for your database?Or table b has stats for the column rate?
>   When stats are updated/created for these tables?
>   if not first create statistics for this column and I am sure your plan will be normal.
>   If you can not create statistics then try to force the same plan as you are getting without rate > 0
>   CTE doesnt improve the code perf as such,there might be excpetion .These are there to make the 
>   code much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to tell the server how to optimize your query by using CTE's, I think you are kidding yourself. You will get better results with indexes. But in any case, you seem to have the CTE part on its head. You want to ask the server to do the CTE first and then evaluate the outside query. Like this perhaps...

```
;with x as (Select a.id, a.date, a.value from a where a.name='xxx')
Select x.date, b.rate, c.type, x.value
From x
  Inner join b on x.id=b.aid
  Inner Join c on b.id=c.bid
where b.rate>0
```

or

```
;with x as (
   Select b.id, b.rate, c.type 
   From b 
     Inner Join c on b.id=c.bid
   where b.rate>0)
Select a.date, x.rate, x.type, a.value
From a
  Inner join x on a.id=b.id
Where a.name='xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **indexes** on **rate** & **name** columns & you will see a great difference.

**EDIT:**

since the columns belongs to two different tables, so two separate indexes will be required

**EDIT:**

[Indexing guidelines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/are-these-good-indexing-guidelines)

Comment: You must also consider the joins.  And in considering the join, the order of selectivity *(just writing `a JOIN b JOIN c` doesn't mean the execution plan does it in that order, and it's the order of the PLAN that matters)*.  In short; this suggestion has merits, but is grossly incomplete.  For example; a composite index on `b(id,rate)` or `b(rate.id)` will be *much* more appropriate than a single field index on `b(rate)`.

Comment: I know it's kind of difficult without the right indexes but the problem here is this is a vendor database and we cannot make any changes to it and we have read-only access to it.

Comment: @user799891 then possibly you should be asking your vendor for help instead of us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to send the optimizer down the right path by forcing a merge join:

select ...
from TableA
left merge join TableB on ...

Answer (score -2):

The portion `b>0` drastically changes it because the server can no longer optimize the query using a clustered index and other methods.  When you add `b>0` that turns this query into a range query which will require a lot more time because it does indeed have to check more values.  There are some optimizations that I believe are already in place such as B-tree organizations for queries like that, but it won't improve it that much.

Comment: This is partially incomplete.  Although those factors do create a different execution plan, taking over 400 times as long to return fewer results implies something important: The execution plan is faulty.  It would have been faster to use the old plan, and then naively filter out the results.  To me this suggests out of date *statistics*, or some other factor.  It does not suggest *(which some may feel is stated by this answer)* that adding `b.rate > 0` will and should ***always*** make this query so dramatically slower.  *[Although I disagree with this answer, I chose not to down vote it.]*

Comment: The expression b>0 is still a SARGable expression and can be used effectively by the optimizer.