# SQL - Query Performance Slow When Joining Two Views with Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-view

I am running the following query in SQL Server which gives me a result in just 5 seconds with 80,000+ rows and 75+ columns:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER AS ItemLedger
    LEFT JOIN VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA AS Characteristics
    ON Characteristics.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode
```

But when I add a WHERE clause to the query it takes too long time to execute the query. It takes more than 5 minutes for 13450 records.

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER AS ItemLedger
    LEFT JOIN VIEW_PRODUCT_WITH_CHARACTERISTIC_COLUMN_DATA AS Characteristics
    ON Characteristics.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode
WHERE (ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode=204 OR ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode=205)
```

What could be the reason? How do I solve this?

Comment: rathar than where condition, use where condition in join and check the speed

Comment: @Ajay2707: why would you think that's going to make any difference?

Comment: @MitchWheat: thought is while filter data via join server and than where condition will first filter the data based on join condition and than in second step where condition apply to filter. I know views are slow down the query if multiple tables in views.  So while given where condition move into join  will give some speedup.

Comment: @MitchWheat No Both view are from other tables

Comment: @Ajay2707 I tried to cut this where condition and put directly on VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER  view still performance are slow. How sql executing queries?

Comment: show the expanded view definitions

Comment: why you do join? correct me if i am wrong. In your statement `select * from VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER` you just call all the data and column from that view and you do `Left Join` to other view and do nothing except related that to your view and your where condition too just from your first view

Comment: @dwir182 actually i am taking some of columns from view 1 and some of from view 2. for digging the error i simplified the query here. I need columns from second view that's why am joining the view. As you can see its not creating any issue if am not putting where clause.

Comment: @Snehal sorry i got confused when i see your join but not related to your select..

Comment: Can you see the plan execution when the query running?

Comment: @dwir182 am not expert to understanding plan of execution. how can i share with you?

Comment: it is hard because it is view so it can be so many table related. You should show your view definitions..

Comment: 'i simplified the query here.' - perhaps oversimplified to the point where there are no obvious problems. It might help if you added the full query, the view definitions and underlying table definitions.

Comment: @Snehal https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ as XML

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks for the link but it supports upto 2 MB. XML plan exceeding that. I can't give the definition of the view. as there any other option?

Comment: nope, you're on your own.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like there is no index on the column VoucherTypeCode.

If VoucherTypeCode is a column of a table in your database, you can try indexing that column (see this [article about creating indexes on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-nonclustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017))

If VoucherTypeCode is a product of multiple columns, you can try indexing the view itself (see this [Article about indexed views on sqlshack.com](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-indexed-views/))

Alternatively, if you can't/don't want to create an index, check out the accepted answer in this [StackOverflow-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457373/10449765)

Comment: Index are not always be the solving problem [See this](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage) and the op say `with 80,000+ rows and 75+ columns` and that's large..

Comment: I will recommend indexing VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER using VoucherTypeCode. Even if you are only using these two vaoucher types you can use Filter options of the index